# Gatsby not working paths deployed on the github pages (adding repo name in the url)

Tags: deployment, path, gatsby, github-pages, gatsby-plugin

I deployed a gatsby website  with the Github pages and I'm having errors like that:
[image]
Locally everything works perfectly, errors occur only on the server.
Seems like the server can not resolve paths correctly.
I'm adding unnecessary repository name after domain. How to remove that?
I tried changing some host options and deploying app again and once it worked properly, IDK why, then I made another deploy and it crushed again.
My gatsby.config:

```
const path = require("path");
const { title, keywords, description, author, defaultLang, trackingId } = require("./config/site");

module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: "/lbearthworks",
  siteMetadata: {
    title,
    keywords,
    description,
    author,
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics",
      options: {
        trackingId,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-manifest",
      options: {
        name: title,
        short_name: "Lb",
        start_url: "/",
        background_color: "#212121",
        theme_color: "#fed136",
        display: "minimal-ui",
        icon: "content/assets/gatsby-icon.png",
      },
    },
    "gatsby-transformer-remark",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "markdown",
        path: `${__dirname}/content`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        name: "images",
        path: `${__dirname}/content/assets/images`,
      },
    },
    "gatsby-plugin-eslint",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline",
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-sass",
      options: {
        data: `@import "core.scss";`,
        includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src/style")],
      },
    },
    ...
  ],
};
```

[Live version](https://lbrobotyziemne.pl/)

[Github Reository](https://github.com/karpinski1994/lbearthworks)

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with GitHub Pages you need to add an extra configuration to your build command, since you are adding a `pathPrefix` variable, you need to allow Netlify how to prefix those paths. Ideally, the build command should look like:

```
"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public"
```

In your case, because you are adding a file-based configuration ([`netlify.toml`](https://github.com/karpinski1994/lbearthworks/blob/master/netlify.toml)), your build command is:

```
[build]
  command = "yarn && yarn testbuild"
  publish = "public"
```

Note that `testbuild` is `yarn test && yarn build`, [according to your repository](https://github.com/karpinski1994/lbearthworks/blob/master/package.json#L90).

So, one workaround is changing your `package.json` command to:

```
"testbuild": "yarn test && yarn build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public",
```

In addition, you should be in `gh-pages` branch as it shows the [Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-gatsby-works-with-github-pages/):

> When you run `npm run deploy` all contents of the public folder will be
> moved to your repository’s `gh-pages` branch. Make sure that your
> repository’s settings has the `gh-pages` branch set as the source to
> deploy from.